# Считывание post/get запросов

Tags: c++, http, библиотеки

В C++ есть что-нибудь для работы с http протоколом, там, просмотр, на какой сайт был отправлен post/get-запрос, модификация отправленых данных?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если надо самому отправлять запросы, то очень удобна [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.github.com/).
Если надо перехватывать запросы чужой программы, то тут скорее надо писать снифер ( перехватывать пакеты сетевые и разбирать уже их ) или перехватывать функции самой программы. Хотя можно написать проксик, который будет модифицировать определенные пакеты как вам надо. Тут может пригодится boost::asio или опять же cpp-netlib.

Answer (score 0):

посмотри в сторону сокетов

Answer (score 0):

Может это вам пригодится?

http://www.helloworld.ru/texts/comp/lang/visualc/vc2/21.htm.